# Reading excel file from node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel

I am trying to read an excel file from node js, But I am getting succeed, Now am working with below set of code

```
var xlsx = require('node-xlsx');

var obj = xlsx.parse(__dirname + '/productExcell.xlsx'); // parses a file 

console.log(obj);
```

The console doesn't print anything for me and also no console executes after parsing statement.

Answer (score 1):

The `node-xlsx` module requires the `excel` module to be installed.

Ensure you have this by running `npm install excell`.

Also make sure that the file you are trying to parse actually exists at the given path. You could do something like the following:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var xlsx = require('node-xlsx');
var xlsFile = __dirname + '/productExcell.xlsx'

fs.exists(xlsFile, function(exists){
  if (exists) {
    var obj = xlsx.parse(xlsFile);
    console.log(obj);
  } else {
    console.log('File does not exist');
  }
});
```

Comment: installing excel seems very hard in windows, It requires lot of dependencies